# Every possible differences in values from corresponding keys of two different dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Every possible differences in values from corresponding keys of two different dictionaries.

***Exception; skip the difference operation from same index and if the difference is greater than 1500 and smaller that -1500***

My Dictionaries:

```
dict_1 = {'A': [100, 200, 300], 'B': [500, 600, 700], 'C': [900, 1000,
 1100]}  
dict_2 = {'A': [150, 250, 350], 'B': [550, 650, 750], 'C':
 [950, 1050, 1150]}
```

Operations to perform:

```
For A
150 - 100 (skip this because of same index)
250 - 100 = 150
350 - 100 = 250

150 - 200 = -50
250 - 200 (skip this because of same index)
350 - 200 = 150

150 - 300 = -150
250 - 300 = -50
350 - 300 (skip this because of same index)
```

And similarly for other keys. I just need the difference in values.

Output expected

150

250

-50

150

-150

-50

My try:

```
 for value2 in dict_2.values():
     for  v2 in value2:
         for value1 in dict_1.values():
             for v1 in value1:
                 if -1500 <= int(v2) - int(v1) <= 1500:
                    if list.index(v2) == list.index(v1):
                        continue
                    writer.writerow([int(v2) - int(v1)])
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of expected output.

Comment: I just need the differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

dict_1 = {'A': [100, 200, 300], 'B': [500, 600, 700], 'C': [900, 1000, 1100]}  
dict_2 = {'A': [150, 250, 350], 'B': [550, 650, 750], 'C': [950, 1050, 1150]}

for key, values2 in dict_2.items():
    for (i1, v1), (i2, v2) in product(enumerate(dict_1[key]), enumerate(values2)):
        if i1 == i2:
            continue

        diff = v2 - v1

        if abs(diff) > 1500:
            continue

        print('{}: {} - {} = {}'.format(key, v2, v1, diff))
```

Output:

```
A: 250 - 100 = 150
A: 350 - 100 = 250
A: 150 - 200 = -50
A: 350 - 200 = 150
A: 150 - 300 = -150
A: 250 - 300 = -50
B: 650 - 500 = 150
B: 750 - 500 = 250
B: 550 - 600 = -50
B: 750 - 600 = 150
B: 550 - 700 = -150
B: 650 - 700 = -50
C: 1050 - 900 = 150
C: 1150 - 900 = 250
C: 950 - 1000 = -50
C: 1150 - 1000 = 150
C: 950 - 1100 = -150
C: 1050 - 1100 = -50
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, traverse two dict values in same key, and use `enumerate` to get the index, and check the index and boundary:

```
def diff_in_dicts(dict_1, dict_2):
    for k in dict_1.keys() & dict_2.keys():
        for i, n1 in enumerate(dict_1[k]):
            for j, n2 in enumerate(dict_2[k]):
                if i != j and abs(n2 - n1) <= 1500:
                    # writer.writerow([int(n2) - int(n1)])
                    print(n2 - n1)
```

test code:

```
dict_1 = {'A': [100, 200, 300], 'B': [500, 600, 700], 'C': [900, 1000,
                                                                1100]}
dict_2 = {'A': [150, 250, 350], 'B': [550, 650, 750], 'C':
        [950, 1050, 1150]}

diff_in_dicts(dict_1, dict_2)
```

output:

```
150
250
-50
150
-150
-50
150
...
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )